# What is the difference between $ and ~ in R-Studio?

Tags: r, database, statistics, symbols

As I understand these two symbols both showing the relations of two variables. I can't understand the difference. Please help

Comment: They do two completely different things. `$` is an indexing operator for data frame columns, read this: https://rspatial.org/intr/4-indexing.html . `~` indicates the division between the left-hand side (response variables) and right-hand side (predictor variables) of a regression formula, read this: https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/formulae.html . There are many other tutorials you could look at besides the ones linked here.

Comment: This is a bit like asking "What is the difference between a cat and a table? As I understand these both have legs. I can't understand the difference." You can try `help("$")` to find out about the `$` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see an example below:

```
# Dataset cars
df <- cars

# $ Indicates a column in the df
df$speed

# ~ in this case is used in linear model to tell the relation between variables
lm(speed ~ dist, df)
```